# Select Distinct in Linq with anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

Consider this LINQ query. It results with an error when a given `blobID.Key` appears more than one.

Is there any way to add distinct here to convert it to dictionary in a safe way?

```
var temp = (from blobID in blobIds
            join blob in blobs on blobID.Value.HashKey 
            equals blob.HashKey
            select new { blobID.Key,  
                          Binder = Load(blob)}
           ).ToDictionary(arg => arg.Key, arg => arg.Binder);
```

Comment: i think you all missing the point here. the fact that the "select new" create an anonymous type make the Distinct() irrelevant, hence, when i convert it ToDictionary, it fails.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.Equals` is overridden for anonymous classes so you can just use `Enumerable.Distinct`:

```
var temp = (from blobID in blobIds
            join blob in blobs on blobID.Value.HashKey equals blob.HashKey
            select new {
                blobID.Key,
                Binder = Load(blob)
            }
           ).Distinct()
            .ToDictionary(arg => arg.Key, arg => arg.Binder);
```

Here, `Distinct` will use the `Default` equality comparer for the anonymous class. The `Default` equality comparer for an anonymous class uses `Object.Equals` which is overridden to return true iff all the properties are equal.

Comment: Heres a link for more information, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336748.aspx#ToDictionary Also contains many other useful examples

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToLookup`. It was made for this.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup(v=VS.90).aspx ToLookup MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be an issue with the dictionary since the key has to be unique.  You could consider using another structure to store the data (a list) which doesn't have that requirement, or you could try Distinct() as @Jason mentioned, or potentially group by the key, and create a dictionary of the group.  THis way, the key is unique, and you store a collection of all entries with that given key.

Depends on your requirements.

HTH.